# Unable to install Conduktor - Depends: libglx0 but it is not installable

Tags: conduktor

While installation I am having package conflicts. This is the response I am receiving.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'conduktor' instead of './Conduktor-2.2.5.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 conduktor : Depends: libglx0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I tried installing with the .rpm extension and it started working. In case someone else faces issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Conduktor does not support Ubuntu 16.04, the `libglx0` library is only available starting from bionic (18.04 LTS): https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&keywords=libglx0&searchon=names

Comment: encountered the same issue

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who is having problens with Conduktor on Ubuntu 20:

Ubuntu 20 updated from libffi6 (required by Conduktor) to libffi7, so you'll end up with this error:

```
$ sudo apt install ./Conduktor-2.7.5.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'conduktor' instead of './Conduktor-2.7.5.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 conduktor : Depends: libffi6 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

You can fix it this way:

- download libffi6 here http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi6_3.2.1-8_amd64.deb
- instal it: `$ sudo apt install ./libffi6_3.2.1-8_amd64.deb`
- now, with success, install Conduktor: `$ sudo apt install ./Conduktor-2.7.5.deb`

Answer (score 0):

This command helped me:
`sudo apt --fix-broken install`